# How to trigger a change event manually - angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Given the following components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'compA',
    template:  template: `<compB [item]=item></compB>`
})
export class CompA {
    item:any;
    updateItem():void {
        item[name] = "updated name";
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'compB',
    template:  template: `<p>{{item[name]}}</p>`
})
export class CompB implements OnInit{
    @Input() item: any;
    someArray: any[];

    ngOnInit():void {
        someArray.push("something");
    }
}
```

As far as I understood that unless the complete `item` object is changed, angular2 does not recognize the changes on `item`. Therefore, I'd like to emit a change event manually for `item` when the `updateItem` method is called. And afterwards, make the child component i.e. `CompB` re-rendered as if angular detected a change in the regular way.

Currently, what I have done is to implement the `ngOnInit` method of for `CompB` and call that method inside `updateItem` method through a `ViewChild` link. Another part of the story is that my actual source has objects like `someArray` which I'd like to be reset in each render. I'm not sure re-rendering resets `someArray` though. Currently, I'm resetting them in the `ngOnInit` method.

So, my question is: how do I trigger re-rendering for changes on deeper elements of a parent object?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)

Comment: @jonrsharpe , I don't want to trigger a change detection process, I want Angular to recognize a change, which cannot be detected with its builtin change recognition mechanism...

Comment: @suat, it is detected, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941696/2545680). I added some clarification

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> As far as I understood that unless the complete item object is
>   changed, angular2 does not recognize the changes on item.

It's not all that straightforward. You have to distinguish between triggering `ngOnChanges` when object is mutated and DOM update of the child component. Angular doesn't recognize that `item` is changed and doesn't trigger a `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook, but the DOM will still be updated if you reference particular property of the `item` in the template. It's because the reference to the object is preserved. Therefore to have this behavior:

> And afterwards, make the child component i.e. CompB re-rendered as if
>   angular detected a change in the regular way.

You don't have to do anything in particular because you will still have update in the DOM.

#### Manual change detection

You can insert a change detector and trigger it like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'compA',
    template:  template: `<compB [item]=item></compB>`
})
export class CompA {
    item:any;
    constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    updateItem():void {
        item[name] = "updated name";
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

This triggers change detection for the current component and all its children.

**But, it won't have any effect in your case** because even though Angular doesn't detect change in `item` it **still runs change detection** for the child `B` component and **updates the DOM**.

**Unless** you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. In this case a way to go for you would be to do a manual check in the `ngDoCheck` hook of the `CompB`:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class CompB implements OnInit{
    @Input() item: any;
    someArray: any[];
    previous;

    constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.previous = this.item.name;
        someArray.push("something");
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
      if (this.previous !== this.item.name) {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    }
}
```

You can find more information in the following articles:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) article.
- [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d)
- [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce)

Comment: Hi i have tried your sample code but ngDoCheck() method executing several time in the application can you explain how to overcome this issue

Comment: Not sure, but I suppose you additionally need `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or detach from change detection?

Answer (score 3):

you can put another input in CompB so when you want change properties of item in CompA just change value of this input.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'compA',
    template:  template: `<compB [item]=item [trigger]=trigger></compB>`
})
export class CompA {
    item:any;
    trigger: any;
    updateItem():void {
        item[name] = "updated name";
        trigger = new Object();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'compB',
    template:  template: `<p>{{item[name]}}</p>`
})
export class CompB implements OnInit{
    @Input() item: any;
    @Input() trigger: any;
}
```